# How to detect if texts are deleted in multiple cells that are not adjacent to each other?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to detect if text/values are being deleted from a number of cells that are not located adjacent to each other so I can execute a routine.

As an example I would like to monitor cell E5, E8, E11 and E14 to detect if text has been deleted from these cell.
If E5 has been deleted, I would like to execute subroutine #1.
If E8 has been deleted I would like to execute subroutine #2.
All the sub-routines are unique. Monitoring E5, E8, E11 and E14 as a range will not work for me.

I don't want to execute the routine if I am adding text to the cell.

I can only go as far as the following routine - which is not working correctly as it does not make a distinction if I am adding text or deleting text.
I also do not know how to monitor multiple cells without using a range?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   
    If Target.Address = "$E$5" Then
    MsgBox "hello"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please confirm that you have the same number of cells as you have subroutines. Also, what should happen if you delete more than one cell at a time? Should more subroutines run? Also, it is important what the subroutines will do. Will they change values in the worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("E5")
  If Target.cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Not Intersect(Target, Union(rng, rng.Offset(3), rng.Offset(6), rng.Offset(9))) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
            Case "E5": Debug.Print "E5 is empty" 'mySubrutine1
            Case "E8": Debug.Print "E8 is empty"
            Case "E11": Debug.Print "E11 is empty"
            Case "E14": Debug.Print "E14 is empty"
        End Select
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

It analyze only the specified cells and do something only if the modified cell is empty.

It exits in case of multiple cells selection. But, it can be easily adapted to also accept multiple deletions. In fact, the next variant should be able do deal with such a situation:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rng As Range, C As Range: Set rng = Range("E5")

  If Not Intersect(Target, Union(rng, rng.Offset(3), rng.Offset(6), rng.Offset(9))) Is Nothing Then
    For Each C In Target.cells
        If C.Value = "" Then
            Select Case C.Address(0, 0)
                Case "E5": Debug.Print "E5 is empty" 'mySubrutine1
                Case "E8": Debug.Print "E8 is empty" 'mySubrutine2
                Case "E11": Debug.Print "E11 is empty" 'mySubrutine3
                Case "E14": Debug.Print "E14 is empty" 'mySubrutine4
            End Select
        End If
    Next C
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Now that it works, I would like to understand the code...what does this code do? I dont understand the offset bit?
`If Not Intersect(Target, Union(rng, rng.Offset(3), rng.Offset(6), rng.Offset(9))) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: This is quite strange - I experimented the code with a different group of cells, say in this case I tried to monitor Cell C11, F11, I11 and L11 and it only seem to work only for cell C11. No changes to the code otherwise but it does not work for F11, I11 and L11. Any thoughts please?

Comment: @Tofulover This line restricts the next part of the code to changing only of the four needed cells.

Comment: @Tofulover You must understand the logic of building the range to be intersected... In your example, the range have the same row, but different columns. So you should use `rng.Offset(0, 3), rng.Offset(0, 6), rng.Offset(0, 9)`... Is it now clearer? It now uses `Offset` to refer the third, sixth and ninth column to the right. You can use -3, -9 to refer columns to the left... 0 from `Offset` means the same row. `Offset(3)` is identic with `Offset(3, 0)` and means three rows down.

Comment: ahh I am starting to see the pattern. I will experiment a bit more. Thanks for that!! Appreciated!

Comment: @Tofulover  You can simple use `Range("E5,E8,E11,E14")`, or `Range(" C11,F11,I11,L11")` instead of that `Union` construction, to set a discontinuous range. It was easy for me to think in terms of `Offset`... It was a little fancy :)

Comment: thanks to your explanation. I now understand more about that offset function. It is still a bit challenging as the concept is new to me. I like that Range("E5,E8,E11,E14") method too - a lot more straightforward that one

Comment: @Tofulover The code as it is, offers more flexibility if you want do the same thing for a different column. You should only change `rng`... And adapting the `Union` logic, you can do the same for any row. And it is good to understand the meaning of such a property, too, I think...